# Not a valid key: eclipsify

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying out the todolist `play framework` application from their documentation. But when I try to create the eclipse project, using `eclipsify` command, I get this error

```
[todolist] $ eclipsify
[error] Not a valid command: eclipsify (similar: eclipse)
[error] Expected '/'
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: eclipsify
[error] eclipsify
[error]          ^
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is now **eclipse** or **idea**, not **eclipsify** or **idealize**.

Comment: You're right! Don't know how I missed `similar: eclipse` in the error.

Comment: I am using Damiya and I am unable to find eclipse.
[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)

Comment: I don't know about eclipse, but `idea` command is not needed anymore because IDEA (Ultimate) can import play projects as sbt-projects. Is it different in eclipse?

Comment: @Cosmolev Scala IDE cannot import an SBT project

Answer (score 2):

Append this piece to your plugins.sbt file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

then use eclipse not eclipsify